# .bashrc loaded in a login shell

Tags: bash, ubuntu, login

I have read that `.bashrc` is loaded when you open a non login shell (for example: `xterm`), and indeed when I opened `xterm`, `.bashrc` was loaded.

But when I opened a login shell (Ctrl+Alt+F#), `.bashrc` was also loaded!

I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu, the user's default `~/.profile` (copied from `/etc/skel/.profile` at account creation time) includes the following section:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Hence, if the login shell is `bash`, it will source the user's `~/.bashrc` as well.

Comment: I'd call that a bug, or at least a misfeature.